Who are the factions fighting against Assad's regime in Syria?
In the past few days, civil war in Syria has apparently resumed, as "rebel groups" have launched attacks on the Syrian military and targets in the Aleppo area.
However, I've been having trouble finding information on who the different factions in these "rebel groups" are. The CNN article linked above notes:

The opposition factions conducting the offensive range from Islamic groups to the moderate Free Syrian Army, which was previously supported by the US and Turkey.

Information circulating on Twitter claims that al-Qaeda is one of the groups fighting against the regime, alongside conspiracy theories that Israel told these groups to launch an offensive for whatever reason. Since unsourced Twitter claims aren't exactly the most trustworthy source, I've tried to search for reports from more mainstream sources on what the different factions are, but without much luck.
The one group consistently named is Hayat Tahrir al-Sham, usually along with "allied factions".
So who are the "allied factions" who are participating in the conflict with the Syrian (and Russian) forces?

"civil war in Syria has apparently resumed" - honestly, I didn't realise it had even stopped.

IDK if HTS needed much direct encouragement. They often fought Hezbollah, which has been weakened by Israel. The part of Syria HTS controls is where celebrations for the death of Nasrallah were held. https://themedialine.org/top-stories/while-opposing-israel-syrians-in-rebel-controlled-idlib-celebrate-nasrallahs-death/

@F1Krazy And it's been going on for long before the latest rounds got publicized:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_Hama_massacre And even before that:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alawite_State

HTS (CSIS article dates from 2018 was originally part of Al-Qaeda, but split amiably and may be less amiable with Al Qaeda nowadays.  Still designated as terrorists by Western countries.  That's the main active group in the Aleppo takeover, apparently.

Not super clear, right now:

Some rebel groups affiliated with the Turkey-backed Syrian National Army (SNA) joined the operation, though the majority of those forces have so far refrained from participating, according to reports.
[...] Turkish security sources said on Thursday that the groups had launched “a limited offensive” towards Aleppo to stop Syrian government attacks targeting the civilian population in Idlib.
A senior Turkish security source told MEE that Turkey had attempted to prevent the offensive to avoid further escalating tensions in the region, especially given Israel's wars on Gaza and Lebanon.

Another source names "Turkish-backed SNA’s Levant Front (al-Jabha al-Shamiya)" as participating. Checking out the latter's wiki page, they had a bit of a fall-out with Turkey recently:

In September 2024, the Levant Front ceased relations with the Turkish-backed Syrian Interim Government and called for the governments dissolution as well as the arrest of SIG prime minister Abdul Rahman Mustafa. This announcement had came after a meeting between Mustafa and a Levant Front delegation arranged by Turkish intelligence, in which Mustafa accused the Levant Front of "terrorist activates" through some factions in the group such as the Ahrar Al-Sharqiya.

So, it's perhaps not so surprising they'd join HTS. By the way, the HTS has tried in various ways to expand their control/influence over the Turkish-sponsored militias, e.g. via the "al-Shahba Gathering", but the latter was reportedly recently disbanded after pressure from Turkey.
Various groups sponsored by Turkey have fought each other recently over disagreements apparently caused by Turkey's rapprochement attempts with Assad (more on that here) and other issues:

The spark for the clashes was the decision by the Ministry of Defense of the Turkey-backed Syrian Interim Government to dissolve the Northern Hawks Brigade on Sep 17.
The Northern Hawks Brigade had opposed both the normalization process between Ankara and Damascus and the opening of the Abu Zandin crossing point near al-Bab. In response to the dissolution, the Northern Hawks took action and joined forces with the Levant Front on Sep 17.

Also

As well as HTS, the factions known to be involved include Ahrar al-Sham, the National Liberation Front, Jaish al-Izzeh, Al-Jabhat al-Shamiya and Harakat Nour al-Din al-Zinki.

FWTW, it was someone speaking Turkish who took down the Russian flag in Aleppo. He finished with a Takbir for good measure though.

Now it looks like the SDF (Kurds) have joined the fight. Or at least the scramble for territory being quickly vacated by Assad's force. But that apparently means some the Turkish sponsored militias will fight against them (SDF):

As a coalition of rebel forces led by the jihadist Hay’at Tahrir al-Sham (HTS) marched on Aleppo and sent regime soldiers fleeing, the SDF took control of strategic locations in eastern Aleppo and formed a corridor to the city from the Euphrates River, briefly capturing key sites such as Aleppo International Airport on Saturday.
The Kurdish-led force later tactically withdrew from many of the sites, while maintaining their hold over Aleppo’s Kurdish-majority neighborhoods of Sheikh Maqsoud and Ashrafiyeh, both long held by the YPG - the SDF’s backbone.
Media affiliated with the Kurdish-led Rojava administration on Sunday reported fierce clashes between the SDF and Turkish-backed Syrian National Army (SNA) in northern Aleppo province, near the Kurdish-held town of Tal Rifaat near Afrin and Shahba.

The Kurds will probably more difficult for Assad and the Russians to dislodge from whatever territory they capture. Because e.g. this August they received US helicopter gunship support when pro-Assad Arab tribal militias and IRGC/Shia ones attacked them. (Of course, Trump might have different ideas about this, once he takes office, as he has lowered US support for the Kurds in his first term.)
But the SDF and HTS are also competing and might clash:

In a statement Sunday saying that it was "fighting the criminal Assad regime," HTS offered safe passage for Aleppo's Kurds — who are concentrated in the Sheikh Maqsud neighborhood — to the Kurdish-controlled northeast. The statement described the Kurds as "an integral part of Syrian society" who "have full rights in common with the rest of this country." The Kurds see the move as an attempt at ethnic cleansing.

Although not much of an official word came from Turkey thus far, except them saying they want stability, the SNA has also made advances, although ostensibly to thwart the Kurds:

Turkey’s state-run Anadolu news agency reported late Sunday that SNA forces had begun entering the center of Tell Rifaat “as part of the Operation Dawn of Freedom, launched against the PKK/YPG’s plans to create a terrorist corridor [connecting the Kurdish zone to Aleppo].”



Question:
Who are the factions fighting against Assad's regime in Syria?

Short Answer:
Complex question because some factions fight only tangentially against the Assad regime while more focused on more direct threats proximal to their own territory.  Here are the primary players in the nearly 15 year Syrian civil war.

Assad Regime, backed by Russia and Iran
Al-Qaeda, or a group who's origin was tied to it but split off from it in 2016,
ISIS
Kurd led, multi ethnic coalition supported by The United States and various Gulf states
Syrian National Army supported by Turkey

Answer

Hayat Tahrir al-Sham (HTS): An Islamist group with origins linked to al-Qaeda, HTS controls significant areas in Idlib province. It has been a dominant force against Assad's regime and has clashed with other rebel factions. Stated goals are to liberate the entire Levant, including Israel. Recently captured Aleppo Syria's second largest city.

Islamic State of Iraq and Syria (ISIS): Although significantly weakened, ISIS remains active in certain regions, opposing all other factions, including Assad's regime.

Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF): coalition of U.S.-backed ethnic militias and rebel groups Led by the Kurdish People's Protection Units (YPG), the SDF is a multi-ethnic alliance controlling parts of northeastern Syria. While primarily focused on combating ISIS, the SDF has had tensions with Assad's forces and Turkish-backed groups.

Syrian National Army (SNA): (supported by Turkey) Also known as the Turkish-backed Free Syrian Army, the SNA is a coalition of opposition groups supported by Turkey. Operating mainly in northern Syria, the SNA has been involved in conflicts against both Assad's forces and Kurdish-led groups.

Various Islamist and Jihadist Groups: Other factions, such as Hurras al-Din (an al-Qaeda affiliate in Syria), operate independently, often engaging in conflicts with both the regime and other opposition groups.


References if you want to read up on it further.

from  Dec 2, 2024: Who is fighting in Syria and why?


Sunni Islam and orthodox islam is basically the faction against the Alawites, because they have a lot of unorthodox religious views including not visiting mosques. The fighting has been continuous and the borders are porous. FSA NLF ISIS HTS SNA...

This answer would be better with data and references for the claims being made.

By "the Alawites", do you mean the Assad regime? From Googling it, it seems that the Alawites support Assad, if only because they fear the consequences if his regime falls to the rebels, but the Assad regime itself is not Alawite.

Bashar continues to identify as Alawite. ..Hafez al-Assad, Bashar’s father, emerged from the french favored alawite military ranks, leveraging his Alawite identity and strong ties within the sect. In 1970, Hafez led a coup that brought him to power and established a regime dominated by Alawite elites.
