What are the factions fighting against Assad ostensibly fighting for?
This is not a question about  who they are or who is supporting them. It is a question of what are they ostensibly fighting for? Assuming they are successful and overthrow Assad what type of government do they claim they will install? Theoretically would they accept a compromise and peace agreement from Assad? What is their claim to be the ones who deserve to rule Syria any more than Assad? Or perhaps to sum up the above, is there an actual political ideological conflict that they are fighting for or does it all boil down to little more than they and Assad both want to rule over Syria, the only  question is who will win the fight to do so.

Why assume that there is only one thing that they are fighting for? There are Islamic fundamentalist factions, republican factions, and ethnic nationalist factions, at least.

Also, bear in mind that Assad is extremely popular, so much so that he managed to win 130% of the votes in government-controlled parts of Syria. So the opposing factions might have that in mind when thinking about whether he has a popular mandate or not.

If they somehow win (unlikely) it will be like Libya: a bunch of groups with different priorities, probably even fighting each other occasionally.

There are too many factions and each has a long list of aims. As such, this Q is too broad and should be narrowed.

As far as I know there are only two rebel groups in the current fighting. HTS and the Syrian National Army. Which other rebel groups are in this round of fighting?

@264champagnebottlesonice In the perspective of Assad vs "rebel groups" there are already instances of factions of the rebels fighting each other. Instead of a love triangle the country is more of a polygon of hate right now.

@Schmerel Another question is already asking who is currently involved: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89979/who-are-the-factions-fighting-against-assads-regime-in-syria

The SDF is currently engaged too, with USAF "BRRRRT" support https://www.reddit.com/r/syriancivilwar/comments/1h5nex3/more_us_a10_action_in_support_of_the_sdf/

SNA is not as homogenous as its name implies. Various sub-groups are more or less following Tukey's orders. Some of those are fighting the Kurds around Tell Rifaat. Others showed up in Khattab, right next to Hama https://www.reddit.com/r/syriancivilwar/comments/1h6nejv/footage_claimed_to_be_from_khattab_where_the/

And even on the Salafist side https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansar_al-Tawhid_(Syria) still has its own forces or at least releases its own footage. https://www.reddit.com/r/syriancivilwar/comments/1h75cls/the_syrian_free_army_during_the_liberation_to/ They are similar to HTS in ideology, but not the same group. Wikipedia claims in another article that they've left the Rouse the Believers Operations Room, but clearly they at least joined this offensive. Unlike HTS, the US has sometimes targeted AaT https://www.counterextremism.com/armed-opposition-groups-nw-syria/ansar-al-tawhid-aat
