How much influence does HTS have in the South of Syria?
In the past couple of days, while HTS took Hama and Homs in central Syria, there's been an uprising in the south as well. Which apparently reached Damascus now. But it's far more nebulous who's involved in the southern uprising. Any details on the groups who lead the latter?

May be included in https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89979/who-are-the-factions-fighting-against-assads-regime-in-syria

I don't think it is realistic to be asking this right now.  The situation is way too fluid and can evolve significantly in the coming weeks.  What we do know is that he is in Damascus and apparently rather welcomed.  But his influence will vary due to lots of factors such as how he behaves, power ratios, regional/religious/ethnic affiliations and how other players joust for power.  A national unity government followed by elections is 1 (unlikely?) possibility, post-Gaddafi division and war another, Taliban-style rule yet another.  Way too early
